# Manipulating data in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

A dumb question. How to manipulate columns in Polars?

Explicitly, I have a table with 3 columns : N , Survivors, Deaths

I want to replace Deaths by Deaths * N and Survivors by Survivors * N

the  following code is not working

```
table["SURVIVORS"] = table["SURVIVORS"]*table["N"]
```

I have this error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object does not support 'Series' assignment by index. Use 'DataFrame.with_columns'
```

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polars isn't pandas.

You can't assign a part of a df.  To put that another way, the left side of the equals has to be a full df so forget about this syntax `table["SURVIVORS"]=`

You'll mainly use the `with_columns`, `select` methods.  The first will add columns to your existing df based on the expression you feed them whereas `select` will only return what you ask for.

In your case, since you want to overwrite SURVIVORS and DEATHS while keeping N you'd do:

```
table=table.with_columns([
                          pl.col('SURVIVORS')*pl.col('N'),
                          pl.col('DEATHS')*pl.col('N')
                         ])
```

If you wanted to rename the columns then you might think to do this:

```
table=table.with_columns([
                          (pl.col('SURVIVORS')*pl.col('N')).alias('SURIVORS_N'),
                          (pl.col('DEATHS')*pl.col('N')).alias('DEATHS_N')
                         ])
```

in this case, since `with_columns` just adds columns, you'll still have the original SURVIVORS and DEATHS column.

This brings it back to `select`, if you want to have explicit control of what is returned, including the order, then do `select`:

```
table=table.select([      'N',
                          (pl.col('SURVIVORS')*pl.col('N')).alias('SURIVORS_N'),
                          (pl.col('DEATHS')*pl.col('N')).alias('DEATHS_N')
                         ])
```

One note, you can refer to a column by just giving its name, like 'N' in the previous example as long as you don't want to do anything to it.  If you want to do something with it (math, rename, anything) then you have to wrap it in `pl.col('column_name')` so that it becomes an Expression.